# Django loaddata error doesn't show message

Tags: python, django, postgresql, sqlite, mezzanine

I have Mezzanine app and my purpose is to move data from sqlite3 to prostgres. 
I found this [solution](http://reinout.vanrees.org/weblog/2011/05/12/sqlite-postgres-django-cms-migrations.html) which solved some erors.
But now I have something wrong again and can't understand what actually happend because I got just name of error **django.db.utils.DataError**.
Here is full Traceback:

`manage.py loaddata dump.json`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\GitRepos\newbesturfu\manage.py", line 14, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 330, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 393, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 444, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\loaddata.py", line 60, in handle
    self.loaddata(fixture_labels)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\loaddata.py", line 90, in loaddata
    self.load_label(fixture_label)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\loaddata.py", line 147, in load_label
    obj.save(using=self.using)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\serializers\base.py", line 173, in save
    models.Model.save_base(self.object, using=using, raw=True)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 738, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 803, in _save_table
    forced_update)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 853, in _do_update
    return filtered._update(values) > 0
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 580, in _update
    return query.get_compiler(self.db).execute_sql(CURSOR)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1062, in execute_sql
    cursor = super(SQLUpdateCompiler, self).execute_sql(result_type)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 840, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 79, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 97, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.DataError
```

I use Windows 10, Django 1.8.3 and PostgreSQL 9.4.

Does anyone know how to show full error message or may be know how to get rid of this issue?

Comment: most likely there is a mismatch between your db schema and your fixture. have you initialised the db tables? are you sure they correspond with the data in the fixture? check the db logs to see if there is info there

Comment: @scytale Yes, I have initialised the db by `manage.py syncdb` command. I'm not sure that new talbes correspond the data in the fixture. I created new mezzanine project and now trying to move data to new Posgresql db. I dont know where to find db logs. I changed log_destination in the postresql.conf but it didn't help. Nothing wrote to log file.

Comment: you'll need to do some investigation into both those things